# {DetachedInstanceError} Parent instance <Car> is not bound to a session; lazy load operation of attribute 'owner' cannot proceed

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I got error message: *{DetachedInstanceError} Parent instance  is not bound to a session; lazy load operation of attribute 'owner' cannot proceed*

My python code:

```
car_obj = my_query_function()  # get a Car object
owner_name = car_obj.owner.name # here generate error!
```

My model:

```
class Person(EntityClass):
    attributes = ['id', 'name']

    name = sa.Column(sa.String(250))


class Car(EntityClass):
    attributes = ['id', 'brand', 'color', 'purchase_time', 'owner_id']

    brand = sa.Column(sa.String(250))
    color = sa.Column(sa.String(250))
    purchase_time = sa.Column(sa.String(250))
    owner_id = sa.Column(DBKeyType, sa.ForeignKey(Person.__tablename__ + '.id'), nullable=False)
    owner = relationship('Person', cascade='all, delete-orphan', backref=backref('car', cascade='delete'), single_parent=True)
```

Is this has something to do with the lazy-loading relationship setting between Car and User (many-to-one association)? How can I fix the relationship? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/loading_relationships.html

Answer (score 15):

I traced the docs and made it work by adding `lazy='subquery'`

```
owner = relationship('Person', lazy='subquery', cascade='all, delete-orphan', backref=backref('car', cascade='delete'), single_parent=True)
```

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/join_conditions.html

Answer (score 5):

Made it work by adding `joinedload_all()` in `session.query(Car).options()`, for example:

```
cars = session.query(Car).options(joinedload_all('*')).all()
session.close()
for car in cars:
     "do your struff"
```

good luck